# Add 'set' to properties of interface in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I am looking to 'extending' an interface by providing set accessors to properties in that interface.  The interface looks something like this:

```
interface IUser
{
    string UserName
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

I want something like this:

```
interface IMutableUser : IUser
{
    string UserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I need the inheritence.  I cannot copy the body of `IUser` into `IMutableUser` and add the set accessors.

Is this possible in C#?  If so, how can it be accomplished?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't see any reason why what you have posted shouldn't work?  Just did a quick test and it compiles alright, but gives a warning about hiding.  This can be fixed by adding the new keyword, like this:

```
public interface IMutableUser : IUser
{
    new string Username { get; set; }
}
```

An alternative would be to add explicit set methods; eg:

```
public interface IMutableUser : IUser
{
    void SetUsername(string value);
}
```

Of course, I'd prefer to use setters, but if it's not possible, I guess you do what you have to.

Comment: Adding new worked great!  Thanks!  Can you update your answer with an example (for others)?

Comment: From practical viewpoint: interfaces evolve very badly over time. All implementers of the interface will break with every change to this contract....

Comment: @PatrickPeters - I assume that comment was directed at the SetUserName method? I don't see issues with the first option. Some of the possible breaks are eliminated if the implementer follows explicit implementation where appropriate.

Comment: @Maslow: no not specifically, my commment was more in generic way. MS has specific guidelines when to use an interface. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229013.aspx

Answer (score 9):

You could use an abstract class:

```
interface IUser
{
    string UserName
    {
        get;
    }
}

abstract class MutableUser : IUser
{
    public virtual string UserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Another possibility is to have this:

```
interface IUser
{
    string UserName
    {
        get;
    }
}

interface IMutableUser
{
    string UserName
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

class User : IUser, IMutableUser
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I need MutableUser to inherit IUser.  I will look into the first method.

Comment: Using an abstract class works.  However, it doesn't seem to be the most elegent solution here.  Will leave this question open for a bit for possible "better" answers.

Answer (score 9):

You can "override" properties in an interface by explicitly implementing the interfaces.  Chris' answer is likely all you'll need for the scenario you've outlined, but consider a slightly more complex scenario, where you need a getter/setter on your class, but the interface only defines the getter.  You can get around this by doing the following:

```
public class MyUser : IUser
{

    IUser.MyProperty { get { return "something"; } }

    public MyProperty { get; set; }

}
```

By explicitly implementing `IUser.MyProperty`, you satisfy the contract.  However, by providing public `MyProperty`, the API for your object will never show the explicit interface version, and will always use MyProperty with the get/set.